# Browserify exclude does not seem to work

Tags: browserify

I am trying to exclude JQuery from my build file:

```
browserify --exclude jquery -g uglifyify -e src/main.js -t partialify -t uglifyify > dist/bundle.min.js
```

Only JQuery is still in the bundle.min.js? Am I doing something wrong? 
https://github.com/substack/browserify-handbook#ignoring-and-excluding

Comment: I'm running into the same issue.  Did you find an answer?

Comment: Nope unfortunately didn't find out yet.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the following?

```
browserify src/main.js --exclude jquery -g uglifyify -t partialify -t uglifyify > dist/bundle.min.js
```

the usage is as follows, i.e. options come after entry files:

```
Usage: browserify [entry files] {OPTIONS}
```